# What are these single letter SQL keywords?

Tags: postgresql, syntax, sql-standard

I am looking at list of SQL keywords here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

There are some single letter keywords there. I cannot find any information about them.
Where can I find the information and what are these for?

Examples,
`A`, `C`, `F`, `G`, `K`, `M`, `P`, `T`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking my copy (of a draft) of the SQL standard (version 2011), I see that **K, M, G, T, P** are mentioned in section **5.2 <token> and <separator>**:

```
<large object length token> ::=
  <digit>... <multiplier>

<multiplier> ::=
    K
  | M 
  | G
  | T
  | P
```

and they obviously mean Kilo, Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta. They are explained in section **6.1 <data type>, Syntax Rules 9**:

```
9) The numeric value of a <large object length> LOL is determined as follows.  
Case:  
    a)  If LOL immediately contains <unsigned integer> and does not immediately 
    contain <multiplier>, then the numeric value of <large object length> is the
    numeric value of the specified <unsigned integer>.  
    b)  If LOL immediately contains <large object length token> or immediately 
    contains <unsigned integer> and <multiplier>, then let D be the value of
    the specified <unsigned integer> or the numeric value of the sequence of 
    <digit>s of <large object length token> interpreted as an <unsigned integer>. 
    The numeric value of LOL is the numeric value resulting from the 
    multiplication of D and MS, where MS is:  
        i) If <multiplier> is K, then 1,024.  
        ii) If <multiplier> is M, then 1,048,576.  
        iii) If <multiplier> is G, then 1,073,741,824.  
        iv) If <multiplier> is T, then 1,099,511,627,776.  
        v) If <multiplier> is P, then 1,125,899,906,842,624.
```

**C and M** are mentioned in **10.2 <language clause>**:

```
<language clause> ::=
  LANGUAGE <language name>

<language name> ::=
    ADA
  | C
  | COBOL
  | FORTRAN
  | M | MUMPS
  | PASCAL
  | PLI
  | SQL
```

I haven't found A. It might have been in older versions of the SQL standard and then removed or might have been added in later versions.